# Illegal start of expression NB

Tags: java, list, arraylist, netbeans, expression

```
    ArrayList<List<BigInteger>> diskpart;
      List<BigInteger> getPartition(Integer n){
         List<BigInteger> aktpart = new ArrayList<> ();
         if(n==1)
         {
             return = aktpart.add(BigInteger.ONE);
             ^
         }
        return = aktpart;
        ^        
        }
```

Illegal start of Expression.

Comment: You are not supposed to write `return = ...`. It is not a variable.

Comment: You probably want to change `new ArrayList<>();` to `new ArrayList<BigInteger>();`.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` after the `return` is wrong. Just drop it:

```
if (n == 1) {
    return aktpart.add(BigInteger.ONE);
}
return aktpart;
```